# How to implement Intrusion Detection System in NS2 ?

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcl, ns2, intrusion-detection

I want to write a TCL script to implement Intrusion Detection System in NS2. I searched a lot, but I could not find proper help. I implemented basic routing protocols in NS2. I have a bit knowledge in TCL. I want to know how to modify a AODV protocol. I request you to help me.

Comment: You have a big problem involving some innovation, but the problem is too big for a good answer. Try splitting it up into smaller pieces; we can help better with smaller pieces of the big problem than the big overall one.

Answer (score 0):

IDS , Intrusion Detection System.

---

1. IDS AODV : Patches for ns-2.35 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/activate-mode-promiscuous-in-aodv-4175539244/#2 ...
   **Simulation examples** : {blackholeaodv__idsAODV__dokurer.tcl, idsaodv2.tcl, idsAODV_mohawad-blackh.tcl, vanet-idsAODDV-blackhole-aodv.tcl} → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs

---

2. IDS AOMDV : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04801.pdf

---

(3) IDS for NetSim : IDS.zip → ids//{DSR/, WLAN/} https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetSim 
.. The code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNYkt4TkpBR3FyVjA/view?usp=sharing